# Google ComputeEngine API running under IIS

Tags: asp.net, iis, google-api, google-compute-engine

I'm writing an application for our Ops department to allow them to manage our Google Virtual Machines through our internal web portal.  I've hit a bit of a wall when trying to deploy the application to IIS.

I'm using the following code, which for the most part is taken directly from the API docs.

```
var certificate = new X509Certificate2(keyFile, "notasecret", X509KeyStorageFlags.Exportable);

var credential = new ServiceAccountCredential(
            new ServiceAccountCredential.Initializer(serviceAccountEmail)
            {
                Scopes = new[] { ComputeService.Scope.Compute }
            }.FromCertificate(certificate));

var service = new ComputeService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
        {
            HttpClientInitializer = credential,
            ApplicationName = "ComputeEngineApp",                
        });

//...
//...

var request = service.Instances.List(_projectId, zone);
var result = request.Execute()
```

The above code works fine when running local unit tests.  However when I try and host the code in IIS, the request.Execute() line hangs forever.  I've left my debugger running for hours, and the Execute method never returns or throws an exception.

I've examined web traffic from my machine using Fiddler and I can see that when using IIS the request is never even sent out.  I've tried various troubleshooting within IIS (app pool settings, user account, etc.) with no luck.  I've burnt about two days at this point trying to figure this one out and I feel like the solution is probably a simple one, but with no error messages or feedback at all from the API method, I'm having a hard time making any progress.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Try request.ExecuteAsync() ... for more info visit this link:  http://www.asp.net/web-forms/overview/performance-and-caching/using-asynchronous-methods-in-aspnet-45